# How to get an array value from php via jquery/ajax and pass it to another php file?

Tags: php, arrays, jquery

Here's my php code, The `$contents` must be passed after the change event..

```
<?php

    if($flag == true){
        $contents = $store; // this is the array that needs to be passed
        $color = array();
        foreach($store as $item){
            $color[] = $item['color'];
        }
        $u_color = array();
        $u_color = array_unique($color);
        echo '<label>Available Colors:</label>
        <select id="color">
            <option>Select a color</option>';
        foreach($u_color as $item){
            echo '<option>'.$item.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }

    ?>
```

Here's my jquery/ajax code that should be triggered after the change event

```
$(function () {
    $('#color').live('change', function () {
        var data = <? php echo json_encode($contents); ?> ;
        var the_array = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/receiver.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                data: the_array
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's my `receiver.php`

```
   <?php

print_r($_POST['data']);

?>
```

Here's what contains my `$contents`:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => 2
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => 4
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [size] => 6
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [size] => 8
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [size] => 10
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [size] => 12
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [size] => 14
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [size] => 16
            [price] => $59.00
            [color] => Black
        )

)
```

Comment: could you put the code of 'receiver.php' ? what is actually your problem?

Comment: That's not how things work (in php & ajax is what I ment ), you need to provide more information. Why is it that your array can exist in file A but not in file B and so needs to be passed via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var the_array = $array.join() ;
```

Will join the array as a comma separated string and this can be passed to the Ajax Request..

Otherwise you can serialize your array and pass the arrayobject to your Request too,

```
 vat the_array = $array.serializeArray();
```

Comment: You said .. $array = array(); //assuming this contains many values

Comment: `var data = "<?php echo json_encode($array);?>"; var the_array= $.parseJSON(the_array);`

Comment: uuuhhhhh this type of question makes my brain hurt. can we not close and get them to just you know ... learn programming or something

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an actual Ajax request here ... use `$.ajax` ... or `$.post` ... or `$.get`

EDDIT & ADD:

`var data = '<?php echo json_encode($array);?>'; var the_array= $.parseJSON(data);`

a complete example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $array = array();
  $array['id'] = '2335';
  $array['data'] = 'data string';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var data = '<?php echo json_encode($array);?>';
  var the_array = $.parseJSON(data);
  // keep in mind that the_array is Object not Array 
  // may be you should convert it to an Array
  // other way is to post 'data' adding it to array  var the_array = ('data': data);   
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firefox `firebug` - debug it and see what `json_encode` returns as a string ... `json_encode` has some options you can try

Comment: why no values? i'm sure my array has values on it.. :(

Comment: if I put that ' or " the firebug returns SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character so I remove it..hmm my code it retrieving it is print_r($_POST[receive_array]);

Comment: And i noticed in my firebug, post data= no value in data

Answer (score 1):

### Send ajax request to page

you can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send your array to server via POST (It thing your code is missing some piece)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'receiver.php',
  data: { myarray: the_array },
  success: function(data){
    // executed on success
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

### Initialize values in rendered page

If you want to pass some code to js in the rendered PHP template, use `json_encode()` to "convert" your PHP array/object into a JavaScript Object Notation string:

```
<script>
var the_array = <?php print json_encode($the_array); ?>;
// ...
</script>
```

### Reply to async (ajax) request

If you want `receiver.php` to return some json to the caller (eg. the success function), just print it

```
<?php

// .. do stuff here ..

header('Content-type: application/x-json');
print json_encode($the_array);

?>
```

You'll then "automagically" get `$the_array` as `data` in your `success:` callback.